# Add pre-written function to onclick of division

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a division and I want a JavaScript function to fire when I click on the division. I've found ways of doing it, but they all involve writing the function and I just want to just fire to function and can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#item').click(view_summary(););
</script>
```

Comment: $('#item').click(view_summary); you need to pass a function in argument (not to call it)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks. If you want to inlcude it as an answer I'll up vote it.

Comment: Thx, I just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$('#item').click(view_summary);
```

you need to pass a function in argument (not to call the function directly unless view_summary return a function itself)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
$('#item').on('click', function() {
   view_summary();
});
```

Comment: That caused the function to fire as soon as the page was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap your code around `document.ready` thus it make sure that all the elements are loaded.
- And use `on click` to bind an event. not just `click`

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#item').on('click', function() {view_summary()});
})
</script>
```